# android Can we have Session Management and time out in app

Tags: android

*hello frnds,,,*

I am working on an application XYZ ,which maintains a session time out at Server end..

Actually on login to service I receive a session token which is used to access further web services and that token expires after certain amount of time say 30 minutes...

The token is then expired as a consequence the different web services used do not show desired response.

Is there any Android specify way to maintain timeout for complete application for being able to automatically redirected at login after timeout(session token expired).

If not,Please provide the either ways( to do with Apache HttpClient, the library that I am using for HTTP access.)

**keen to know about any android specific way to do this..**

With Regards,

Arpit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any Android specify way to maintain timeout for complete application for being able to automatically redirected at login after timeout(session token expired).

Use a static data member that represents your token and the time it was validated. Check the token in `onResume()` of each activity. If the token is missing or is out of date, redirect the user to the login activity.